# Is there a difference between the `displaymath` and `equation*` environments?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

The [`amsmath` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) says

> Basic LaTeX doesn’t provide an `equation*` environment, but rather a  functionally equivalent environment named `displaymath`.

Are they *really* the same or is there a catch? Maybe in interaction with some other packages?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Their effect is similar but they are differently programmed. `equation*` builds on amsmath macros and is therefore more compatible to other amsmath environments and commands.

For instance, within LaTeX's `displaymath` environment you cannot use a `split` environment, even if you loaded amsmath. But within `equation*` it's possible.

amsmath redefines `\displaymath` such that it uses `equation*`. That means, after you loaded amsmath, there won't be a difference any more between those two environments. Further, LaTeX's `displaymath` is fragile, amsmath makes it robust.

To see that, here are two lines of `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\displaymath{\[}
\def\enddisplaymath{\]\@ignoretrue}
```

And these two lines are at the very end of `amsmath.sty`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

To sum up, if you use amsmath, which is very recommendable for math texts, you don't need worry about `\displaymath`.

Comment: Your second and third paragraphs seem in opposition.

Comment: @Ryan: it's for the case that one really would like to use the original `displaymath` environment instead of the one of amsmath. It's possible to save it to another name and use the original one together with amsmath. Then we could see the difference and the incompatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the relevant definitions in Section 55.2 of `source2e.pdf` and lines 2523–2667 of `amsmath.sty` LaTeX aliases `\begin{displaymath}` to `\[` and `\end{displaymath}` to `\]`, where `\[` and `\]` are wrappers around `$$` with some checks.  `amsmath` redefines `\[` to `\begin{equation*}` and `\]` to `\end{equation*}`, which in turn wraps around `$$` with some checks.   So they do the same thing, and as Stefan notes, once you load `amsmath`, they literally do the same thing.