# Strange behavior by \qedhere in align environment without alignment mark (&)

Tags: align, amsart

I noticed some strange behavior in the `align*` (or just `align`) environment. The code

```
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    C=1 \qedhere
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}`
```

puts overlaps the tombstone with the equation, whereas

```
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    C &=1 \qedhere
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}`
```

properly puts the tombstone to the right.

What is causing this strange behavior? What exactly is the ampersand doing here?

Comment: The `align` environment without an `&` is useless; there's `gather` for centering equations.

Comment: @egreg I've always used `align*` without an `&` and only one equation as if it were equivalent to the `displaymath` environment. (This is how I noticed the strange behavior I'm asking about.) Is it somehow or incorrect or bad to use `align*` as `displaymath`?

Comment: They aren't equivalent. For one equation there's `equation*`, for more non aligned equations there's `gather*`; `align*` is for aligned equations (say at a relation symbol). Yes, it's bad to use `align*` as `displaymath`.

Comment: @egreg I still don't see why they're not equivalent (and hence why it's bad to use `align*` as `displaymath`). Is there a technical difference?

Comment: For example, `align*` without `&` doesn't work with `\qedhere`. :)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments explain why you should use the `align` environment only when you needs things to be aligned.  Otherwise you should use the `gather` environment.

Not that I am recommending this but, if you insist on using the `align` environment without really aligning anything, you could just add the `&` before the `\qedhere`:

```
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    C=1 &\qedhere
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
```

or after the end of the `align` environment. Of course this results in the `\qed` symbol on the following line

```
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    C=1
  \end{align*}\qedhere
\end{proof}
```

If you do not like the `\qed` symbol on the subsequent line, you can adjust `\belowdisplayskip` as follows:

```
\begin{proof}\belowdisplayskip=-12pt
  \begin{align*}
    C=1
  \end{align*}\qedhere
\end{proof}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in the case that I only have one line of math, shouldn't I use the `displaymath` environment (r, equivalently (I think), `\[...\]`) instead of `gather`?

Comment: Sure you can, but I thought the question was about using the `\qed` symbol with `align`.

Comment: Yes, it was. I'm just wondering if the `gather` recommendation was appropriate in this case. Is `gather*` with one line of math equivalent to `displaymath`?

Comment: You should post a separate question, so that if others have the same question in the future they will be able to find it.

Comment: See if this question regarding [difference between displaymath and equation environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/is-there-a-difference-between-the-displaymath-and-equation-environments) answers your question.