# \qedhere behavior in different environments

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, amsthm, proofs

I am making use of `\qedhere` in proof environments in order to avoid extra space when the proof ends in an equation. I am wondering about why it behaves differently in different environments.

- Apparently, \qedhere does not work in an `equation` environment, when using the showonlyrefs feature from the `mathtools` package? I get the following error: `A <box> was supposed to be here. \end{equation}`
- When using the `amsmath` package, it does not give an error between a pair of `$$`, but it does not flush the `\qed` box to the right, so it does not behave as desired. The same goes for the `gather` environment.
- It works in an `align` environment, but only if `&` is ever used, see [Strange behavior by \qedhere in align environment without alignment mark (&)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32056/strange-behavior-by-qedhere-in-align-environment-without-alignment-mark)
- It works as desired in square brackets `\[\]`

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        Too much space afterwards:
        \[
        a=b.
        \]
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        Works fine:
        \[
        a=b.\qedhere
        \]
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        Not flushed right:
        $$
        a=b.\qedhere
        $$
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        Not flushed right:
        \begin{gather}
            a=b.\qedhere
        \end{gather}
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
        Box completely misplaced:
        \begin{align}
        a=b.\qedhere
        \end{align}
    \end{proof}
    \begin{proof}
    Stuff in comments gives error.
%       \begin{equation}
%       a=b.\qedhere
%       \end{equation}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

which looks like
[image: MWE]

Why do I get these different behaviors, and what is the preferred way of using `\qedhere`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$$` is **not** supported in LaTeX. So your third example **must** be dismissed.

Also, `\qedhere` is not compatible with numbered equations, independently on how they show or not with `showonlyrefs`. After all, where should the tombstone be placed when there is an equation number at the right margin?

Finally, `align` *requires* at least one `&` in order for `\qedhere` to work. (Never use `align` for a single equation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Too much space afterwards: (expected)
\[
a=b.
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Works fine: (OK)
\[
a=b.\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

%\begin{proof}
%Not flushed right: (unsupported)
%$$
%a=b.\qedhere
%$$
%\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Not flushed right: (no, if you do right)
\begin{gather*}
a=b.\qedhere
\end{gather*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Box completely misplaced: (no)
\begin{align*}
a&=b \\
a&=b.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Stuff in comments gives error. (no)
%   \begin{equation}
%   a=b.\qedhere
%   \end{equation}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See my comments in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I get form this that basically all environments will work just fine with `\qedhere`, if you tell the compiler explicitely that they are supposed to be unnumbered, right? I overlooked this, because the last equations of my proofs have never had numbers so far. The difference is only about the way these environments handle this conflict between equation number and qed box, which happens in different ways for `align`, `gather` and `equation`.

Comment: I'm new to the `showonlyrefs` feature, so I learned now that the compiler can not figure out itself that there is no conflict between equation number and `\qedhere` when using `showonlyrefs`