# Is gather* equivalent to displaymath?

Tags: environments, amsmath

Is `gather*` with one line of math equivalent to `displaymath`?

Comment: Does this question regarding [difference between displaymath and equation environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/is-there-a-difference-between-the-displaymath-and-equation-environments) answer your question?

Comment: By "equivalent", do you mean in terms of spacing and alignment (both vertical and horizontal)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not:  the vertical spaces before and after the display are different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Text
\begin{gather*}
  a=b
\end{gather*}
Text
\begin{displaymath}
  a=b
\end{displaymath}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have a very long equation in a `\[...\]`, the space between the binary operators (like `+` and `\times`) will shrink to make the equation break the margin as little as possible (as happens with an equation in an ordinary paragraph; I'm assuming you're using Computer Modern fonts here). This space never shrinks inside a `\begin...\end{gather*}`.

This space also shrinks when necessary in an equation in `\begin...\end{equation}`, and never in an equation in `\begin...\end{gather}`.

By the way, very old versions of `amsmath` *did* define `\[...\]` and `\begin...\end{equation}` as a one-line `\begin...\end{gather*}` and `\begin...\end{gather}`, respectively. See "Changes in amsmath 2.0" [here](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amslatex/math/diffs-m.txt). The first edition (1994) of *The LaTeX Companion* is no longer correct about `\[...\]` and `\begin...\end{equation}` (see page 243).