# gather is not aware of abovedisplayshortskip

Tags: spacing, amsmath

So in the following example we can see that
`gather` does not insert `\abovedisplayshortskip`
but probably inserts `\abovedisplayskip`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
        %\begin{gathered}
            123
        %\end{gathered}
    \end{equation}
    \lipsum[1]

    \newpage

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{gather}
            567
    \end{gather}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[Boris's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33484/51022)
mentioned this
but it does not tell me how to avoid it.
What is the correct way to bring back `\abovedisplayshortskip`?
Does `gathered` inside `equation` produce the correct spacing?

Comment: This should almost certainly be considered a bug; please report it.

Comment: Waiting for the second opinion.

Comment: @Symbol1 It has been like this from day 1 of `amsmath` (it was the same with its ancestors).

Comment: @barbarabeeton documented feature I think, not bug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I think this is in the (long neglected) list of bugs and requests; please check.  (I don't question that it has been there forever and is known.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton amsmath-group10/b-461.tex

Answer (score 3):

`gather` is like `align` and is always full width. This is the main reason why multi-line display environments should never be used for single line displays, and `equation` and `\[` are still needed.

Comment: Years ago I saw a prototype Morten did, I think it was of gather, which could do the same as equation is needed. Don't know what happend to that code

Comment: @daleif yes all the ams displays do the measuring pass so in principle they could track the first and last line width and do something, ....

Comment: I have been using `align` for years and did not notice this!

Comment: @daleif User wea0 proposed a solution for align, but not for gather, in this TeX
StackExchange [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386052/295947).