# equation* environment or \[ \]?

Tags: math-mode, environments, starred-version

So, I'm writing a mathematics paper, and let's say I have the following:

```
\begin{equation*}
2+2=4
\end{equation*}
```

Is this the proper way to do an unnumbered equation, or is it preferred to do the following:

```
\[ 2+2=4 \]
```

My question really is: what's the difference between doing `\begin{equation*}` and `\begin{equation*}` versus doing `\[ \]`? Is there a setting in which one may be preferred over the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `equation` environment gives you a numbered displayed formula, not `equation*` nor `\[..\]`. Note that you need the `amsmath` package for the `equation*` environment. With this package loaded, `equation*` has then the same meaning as `\[..\]` (unnumbered displayed formula). See here for more information: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/is-there-a-difference-between-the-displaymath-and-equation-environments

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to and read the comments there.

Comment: Thank you `fpast` and `AboAmmar`! Your comments and the articles to which you linked were quite helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`equation*` is defined by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). So, if you're loading `amsmath`, then there is no difference [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), as it executes the following at the end:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```